# Spark - Should SparkSession be only one?

Tags: apache-spark

In some example code, SparkSession instance is made singleton.
Does that mean there should be only one instance of SparkSession?
What happens SparkSession if there are more than one? Can they(SparkSessions) interact with each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be only one instance of the SparkSession (and SparkContext) per  JVM. You won't be able to create multiple session instances.

Comment: Why *there can be only one instance of the SparkSession* ?  What's the motivation or  limit behind it ? I dont think this anwser match the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The SparkSession object is a Singleton, so there is only one per client.

You can easily verify this by yourself by opening a SparkShell:

> scala> spark.toString
>
> res7: String =
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@d76a6bd
>
> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
>
> scala> :paste // Entering
>   paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
>
> val spark = SparkSession    .builder()
>   .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")    .getOrCreate()
>
> // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
>
> 17/02/06 07:25:48 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Use an existing
>   SparkSession, some configuration may not take effect. spark:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession =
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@d76a6bd
>
> scala> :paste // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
>
> val spark = SparkSession    .builder()
>   .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")    .getOrCreate()
>
> // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
>
> 17/02/06 07:25:40 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Use an existing
>   SparkSession, some configuration may not take effect. spark:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession =
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@d76a6bd

As you can see in all three cases we are getting back the same object @d76a6bd